# Basic jQuery listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I realise this is a very dumb question, but I can't seem to understand how to get a jQuery listener to work.
I've added the scripts to the html header

```
<script src="js/http_code.jquery.com_jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/calc.js"></script>
```

Where I have an input field

```
<input type="text" size="19" id="infield">
```

And in the .js file I have the following

```
    $('#infield').keydown(function(){
        alert("Alert");
    });
```

But when I write anything into the text field, nothing happens, can somebody tell me where I messed up?

Comment: is the input field before or after the script tags?

Comment: @DanielA.White after, sorry I forgot to mention the script tags are in the header

Comment: theres plenty of examples out there - the dom has to be ready.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enclose this inside a [document.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) event

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
    $('#infield').keydown(function(){
        alert("Alert");
    });
} );
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, that helped. So does that mean that the js code was attempting to apply the listener to a non-existing element, because the script was declared in the header?

Comment: @seMikel yes, precisely. You need to make sure that dom is loaded successfully before assigning events to them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ready state (wait for Jquery to be load) then i advice you to use `$.on()` method if you'll lately modify DOM:

```
$(function () {
     $("body").on('change','#infield', function(){alert("Alert");});
});
```

Comment: Using the `on` or `keydown` doesn't make a difference in this case

Comment: you're right @nem, that's why i said 'use ready state' ie document.ready event. what do you think about using $.on() prefer to $.click or $....?

Comment: yes but you also sad to use the `on` method, which is unnecessary :). Look at @gurvinder372 answer

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Using `on` doesn't really offer any advantages and distracts from the actual problem which is that the code is run before the DOM is ready. Regardless of the method he uses to handle events, it won't work unless he does it when the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

The same code is working here. Double check your jquery file path and other things. Also, check your console for any error messages.

```js
    $('#infield').keydown(function(){
        alert("Alert");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" size="19" id="infield">
```

Comment: This works because SO snippets call the code **after the DOM is ready**, his code still doesn't work on itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `keypress` jquery function

```
$('#infield').keypress(function(){
  alert("Alert");
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kekyafq1/